# Password confirm redirecting back to original POST request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-9

I want to get prompted to confirm your password every time when user submit a form and then process the post request data.

Upon hitting the submit button, the password confirm will show which will force user to confirm his password. After successful authentication, I would like the submit request (ie. POST request) to fetchResult method for performing further process.

But when I use this middleware, It took me password confirm and after entering password it redirects to same form page.

Here is my route code:

```
Route::post('fetchResult', [ReportController::class, 'fetchResult'])
    ->name('fetchComplaintResult')
    ->middleware('password.confirm:password.confirm,1');
```

After submitting confirm password, it redirects to same form page. I can not submitting form data.
How can I POST to a URL after the user has successfully confirm password?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can only use that `password.confirm` feature if you combine it with a `Route::get()`. Not to enter your password for confirmation.

It also caches the "acknowledgement" for a period of time. So if you use this for security, it's not that secure.

Here's a discussion about your same issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/41577